# Finding digest of kernel mailing list

Tags: linux-kernel

I am looking for the digest of the LKML.  The Dell site doesn't seem to have it, even though several places link to it.  Additionally, googling just comes up with old links.   Does the "digest mode" still exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell used to host the digest, and the [LKML FAQ](http://vger.kernel.org/lkml/) still links there, but [it no longer seems to be available](http://lists.us.dell.com/mailman/listinfo), and there doesn't seem to be any other digest. You'll find other ways of following LKML in the FAQ, including [LWN's excellent coverage](https://lwn.net/Kernel/).